# Gradle - Company repository needs ssl client certificate

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

We are trying to switch to gradle. Everything works fine but i have a problem with an internal repository which is only accesable with a client certificate which resides on a pkcs#11 token.

With maven i just had a .mavenrc file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAVEN_OPTS=" $MAVEN_OPTS \
        -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 \
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE \
            -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs11 \
            -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE \
            -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs11 \
"
```

so i put these java options into my gradlew wrapper script at the beginning:

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=" \
-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs11 \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs11 \
"
```

when i run ./gradlew build i get asked for my pin of my token but then the request of the artifacts fail with 401. At the server there is no client certificate arriving.

$ ./gradlew --stacktrace compileJava

```
:compileJava
SunPKCS11 loading /etc/opensc/opensc-java.cfg
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
Information for provider SunPKCS11-OpenSC
[lots of debugging infos from sub pkcs11]
sunpkcs11: getting provider callback handler
sunpkcs11: getting default callback handler
[ entering PIN ]
sunpkcs11: login succeeded
sunpkcs11: user already logged in
sunpkcs11: user already logged in
sunpkcs11: user already logged in
sunpkcs11: user already logged in

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve group: ....
  Required by: ...
   > Could not GET 'https://nexus/PATH...'. Received status code 401 from server: Authorization Required
   > Could not GET 'https://nexus/PATH...'. Received status code 401 from server: Authorization Required

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
[...]
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not GET 'https://nexus/PATH...'. Received status code 401 from server: Authorization Required
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.http.HttpResourceCollection.processHttpRequest(HttpResourceCollection.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.http.HttpResourceCollection.initGet(HttpResourceCollection.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.http.HttpResourceCollection.getResource(HttpResourceCollection.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.http.HttpResourceCollection.getResource(HttpResourceCollection.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.ResourceCollectionResolver.getResource(ResourceCollectionResolver.java:304)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.ResourceCollectionResolver.findStaticResourceUsingPattern(ResourceCollectionResolver.java:248)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.ResourceCollectionResolver.findResourceUsingPattern(ResourceCollectionResolver.java:234)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.ResourceCollectionResolver.findResourceUsingPatterns(ResourceCollectionResolver.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.MavenResolver.findIvyFileRef(MavenResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:223)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DependencyResolverAdapter.getDependency(DependencyResolverAdapter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$1.create(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository$1.create(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:51)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CacheLockingModuleVersionRepository.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository.resolveModule(CachingModuleVersionRepository.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository.findModule(CachingModuleVersionRepository.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleVersionRepository.getDependency(CachingModuleVersionRepository.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.IvyContextualiser$1.invoke(IvyContextualiser.java:44)
    at $Proxy34.getDependency(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.findLatestModule(UserResolverChain.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain.resolve(UserResolverChain.java:52)
    ... 91 more
```

It seems that gradle (groovy) supports standard java ssl properties as it asks for the PIN but then it doesn't succeed.

Everything works fine if i run it with a simple java class like this:

```
 java URL url = new URL("...");
 InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(is);
 String inputLine;
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);
 in.close();
```

Calling it like this works fine:

```
java -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=pkcs11 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs11 jget/JGet
```

ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs11 \
    "

this is my build.gradle

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = "1.0-milestone-9" }
apply plugin: "java"
repositories {   maven { url "https://developer/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty" }  }
dependencies { compile "org.projectx:tools:1.0" }
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue at http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2234 as it seems to be a bug since milestone-6
it works with milestone-5, so if anybody needs this feature, use milestone-5 and wait for this bug to be fixed.

Comment: Seems now it's already resolved. Probably You can just accept your own answer)